# Run shell script on server startup to run multiple servers (CentOs 7)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, init

Hi its my first attempt at running init scripts.

I'm using **chkconfig** for running a script file located in /etc/init.d/serverstartup. I've setup **2345** on level & **016** off and added **# chkconfig: 2345 99 01** to script.

My script starts 3 node servers but i get **`ERRORbind EADDRINUSE`** While i reboot my server & if i kill a server for restart, more and more instances start running.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: "if i kill a server for restart, more and more instances start running." could you elaborate more this to get clear point?

Comment: @pmverma :  I'm killing server on one port by "kill -9". But when i use "ps -ef" to list servers, they keep on increasing in number.

Comment: Could you please update `serverstartup` script?

Comment: @muradin :

#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 99 01

cd /path to server/
nohup node ForeverMonitor.js SERVER_NAME=development <OTHER PARAMS>

Comment: Did you add `chkconfig` into the end of your script? It is not a usual behavior.  I suggest you to read this material first. [bootupHowto] (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto)

Comment: May be you will running your node server using node module like forever. One thing, forever restarts the sever each time with new pid when your server exit, but there is max options available to run at most xx time. see here [https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever]

Comment: @muradin #chkconfig was my second line in script. I'll look into your script. What run levels should i use on and off ? I'm only using system as Command-Line root user. Its a linode server.

Comment: Basically I need my script to run once on startup and then linux should forget about it and not keep its track.

Comment: Just write your script in `/etc/init.d/yourscript`, Make it executable `chmod +x yourscript` and `update-rc.d yourscript defaults (lownumber) (highnumber)`.

Comment: @muradin : What do (lownumber) (highnumber) mean ?

Comment: They are bounds for service priorities, low means your script will run after all services lower that your low number and sooner than services bigger than high number.

Comment: @muradin : update-rc.d doesn't work on centos

Answer (score 1):

The error code **"ERRORbind EADDRINUSE"** means that the port on which you are trying to start your server is already used by another application.

Changing your node server port to another unused port will solve the problem.

Comment: I know what the error means. The think is that the service serverstartup keeps on running the servers if they are killed/restarted. 
I want the script to run just once. Its usually running 3-4 times so the error.

Comment: @vashishatashu: What do you mean one time? The script will run on each startup.

Comment: @muradin I mean on reboot it ran once. Then during same session if i kill a process run by script, it spins process again and again.

Comment: @vashishatashu see my comment above.

Comment: @pmverma : I'm killing ForeverMonitor to kill my node process. So it should not be a problem.

Comment: @vashishatashu, thats is the point. You must stop your ForeverMonitor server using forever stop command, not killing it. If you start your script using forever, then it start two process, the forevermonitor itself and your server. so if you stop using forever stop command, it will properly stop both process. And if you are killing manually only the forevermonitor process, then your own server process will still running, and next time you will get ""ERRORbind EADDRINUSE"" error.

Comment: @pmverma 
Hi i followed these steps :

 - create script in /etc/init.d/myscript
 - Add # chkconfig: - 99 01 to script. 
   
   99 : startup sequence 01: end sequence
 - chkconfig --add myscript
 - chkconfig --level 3 myscript on   : for runLevel 3
 - chkconfig --list      : confirm changes

Then stopped all my node & Forever processes & reboot the system. Still Address In Use.

Comment: @pmverma : I'm using forever programatically. So if i stop it by CLI, will there be any issue ?